# Geometric justification of the inner product

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the picture $a$, $b$,$c$ and $d$ are the lengths of the segments.

Why $ab$ = $cd$ ?
Thanks

ps: it's the geometric justification of the inner product

[image]

Comment: Is this true?  Computing the cosine of the vertex angle, I'd think you'd get $\frac ca = \frac {a+b}{c+d}$, no?

Comment: Are $b$ and $d$ supposed to be the lengths of the sides from the common vertex? The diagram you have drawn looks a bit ambiguous. Two approaches: consider the cosine of the vertex angle. Or consider the small triangle and the large one as similar triangles (angles are equal) so the ratios of corresponding sides are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim only holds if $b$ and $d$ are the whole triangle side lengths of the larger of the two similar right triangles draw on the angle at the left, rather than - as they appear to be - the incremental lengths. Because then, due to the triangle similarity, $\dfrac{a}{c}=\dfrac{d}{b}$ and your result would follow.

Comment: Remark $c/a=d/b=cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the common angle.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{a}{c+d}=\frac{c}{a+b}$$ and we can not get which you wish.